# Pulling tables from a website into Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have to create a macro to pull some tables from a website and then make it filterable on the user-end via some pre-defined categories. I have determined the best way to do this (or at least the way I understand the best) is the winhttp get method as I have table IDs that its pretty easy for me to grab via the webpage's source page that stay consistent.

However, I am pretty new at coding in VBA and coming at this from the perspective of someone whose mostly worked in HTML5 and javascript so I am trying to get a better idea of the general process of roughly how I might want my code to look like format wise in terms of the initial pull and populate requests.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some generic sample code to get you going.

```
Sub Yahoo_BS()

Dim xmlHttp As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, Tr As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, Td As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    myURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/balance-sheet?p=SBUX"
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("Pos(r)")


    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each Tr In TR_col
        Set TD_col = Tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each Td In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = Td.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Note: you need to set a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.